# Why isn't openssl s_client passing my private key to proxytunnel?

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssl, ssh-tunnel, openssl

I currently have HAProxy set up on my home PC and I am attempting to access it through a HTTP proxy.  Currently I am accessing the SSH logon prompt like so:

```
openssl s_client->proxytunnel->HTTP(S) proxy->remote HAProxy->SSH server
```

I am getting to the point where I receive the `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH` prompt but for some reason it just hangs at the prompt and doesn’t pass through the private key.

Here’s the commands I am executing on the client side & how I set up proxy tunnel to use the organization's proxy:

```
proxytunnel -p httpproxy.organization.com:8080 -d ssh.homeserver.com:443 -a 7000
```

Next I am running `openssl` like so:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:7000 -quiet -key /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But for some reason the certificate does not appear to get passed through.  I am most likely missing a step so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Accidentally had -cert instead of -key in the openssl command...I've corrected this.

Comment: It did not solve the issue, I just typed it wrong inside the post.  Apologies :).

Comment: I've used 400, 600, and 700 all to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are confusing the clients of two completely different protocols.**

The `openssl s_client` tool is purely a **TLS (SSL)** client; it is capable of peeling away the TLS layer that HAproxy or stunnel might add. Once that's done, however, it merely transfers arbitrary data from one end to another. The prompt you're seeing is the initial SSH handshake, and the server expects you to reply to it; therefore, you still need to run a program like `ssh` that would talk the **SSH** protocol on top of the TLS tunnel.

Usually `ssh` connects to the server over TCP directly, but you can use the `ProxyCommand` option tell it to go through another program:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="openssl s_client -connect localhost:7000 -quiet" dummyname
```

---

If you have a SSH keypair, you'll need to specify it as an option to `ssh` as well:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_workplace -o ProxyCommand.....
```

(Don't need this for `~/.ssh/id_rsa` though – it is used by default.)

---

The s_client options `-cert` and `-key` are of course for authenticating to the TLS server. However, they need a full X.509 certificate as "-cert"; just the public key isn't enough, as it would be for SSH.

Comment: grawity, I'm doing something a little funky here in the first place--I've followed this guide http://blog.chmd.fr/ssh-over-ssl-episode-4-a-haproxy-based-configuration.html as the proxy blocks SSH outbound so I'm trying to encapsulate it in SSL.  I am able to access my SSH console without the HTTP proxy in place simply by using the ProxyCommand within the ssh configuration file...I'm trying to get around the fact that I don't know how to direct openssl through the proxy without proxytunnel....I'm sure I am a bit confused but get what I'm saying?

Comment: Woohoo!  Looks like I got it!  Needed to use socat to bridge the connection like so: socat TCP-LISTEN:8888 OPENSSL:localhost:7000,verify=0, then connect using SSH like: ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@127.0.0.1 -p 8888.  Having an issue with the connection dropping quickly but I think I can figure that out.